# Building Groups out of Simple Groups?

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

This is only mostly a conceptual question.

When beginning to study simple groups you will repeatedly hear something along the lines "we use simple groups to build up larger more complicated groups". I want to know exactly what we mean by this? (With examples if possible)

A la Jordan-Holder we know that every finite simple group has a composition series (whose factors are simple groups) and, in general, that if a group has a composition series it is of constant length and the factors have, at most, been permuted. However, this doesn't even provide a way of identifying a group as I imagine many groups can have the same composition factors?

Looking to really develop my intuition on this one. Cheers!

**Edit**

Say $G$ is a finite group. Then $G$ has a composition series. Is $G$ always isomorphic to the direct product (sum) of its composition factors?

Comment: We know that all groups can be broken into simple groups. The real innovation of the 20th century was a complete characterisation of what those finite simple groups were - the enormous theorem.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel When you say broken into simple groups, how do you mean? Not every group has a composition series.

Comment: _Every_ finite group has a composition series.

Comment: So not all groups but all finite groups then?

Comment: Yes. The enormous theorem never says anything about infinite groups.